# Error loading XAML into frames

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a XAML file in my app and I am trying to load other XAML files into it via the frame control however, its not working. I am getting an error `Content for the URI is invalid`. The error just pops up as a dialog error when I run the application so there is no stack trace available for it.

Below is the code for my "master page":

```xml
<navigation:Page x:Class="SilverAIM.BusinessCenter.BusinessCenterMaster" 
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
           mc:Ignorable="d"
           xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
           d:DesignWidth="758" d:DesignHeight="480"
           Title="BusinessCenterMaster Page">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <navigation:Frame Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="0,248,0,0" Source="Test.xaml" Name="testFrame" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="758" />
    </Grid>
</navigation:Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using a ContentControl instead of Frame.